# Is there vim text object for python identifiers

Tags: vim, python

I've recently been writing Python quite a lot, and one of the rougher edges when editing it in vim has been the following:

Suppose I have an identifier that has several dots

```python
os.path.join(path, file)
```

and I want to change that to e.g.

```python
self.get_path(file)
```

Now I struggle with selecting the whole of `os.path.join` and will probably use a repeated `diw`/`dw` or some `t`/`f`-motions, which is quite error prone.

**Q**: Is there some built-in command or a plugin that would select this in one go? Maybe along the lines of a text-object `ii` (inside identifier), so that I could just type `ciiself.get_path<ESC>` from any point inside `os.path.join`?